# PhpSpreadsheet corrupted xlsx file

Tags: php, xlsx, xls, phpspreadsheet

I have issue when trying to download xlsx file. It works just fine when i test it locally, but when i upload it to production server, file gets corrupted.

this is the file output:
[image]

this is code im using:

```
<?php

    require 'conn.php';
    require 'vendor/autoload.php';

    use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
    use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx;
    use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory;


    $spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();
    $sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
    $sheet->setCellValue('A1', '#');
    $sheet->setCellValue('B1', 'First');
    $sheet->setCellValue('C1', 'Last');
    $sheet->setCellValue('D1', 'Handle');

    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats- 
    officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="text.xlsx"');
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
    $writer = IOFactory::createWriter($spreadsheet, 'Xlsx');
    $writer->save('php://output');
    die;
```

i tried changing header to, it did not help:

header('Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel');

Comment: Check the file encoding, seems to me is wrong either while creating the file or while opening.

Answer (score 6):

I think that will be ok if you add cleaning of the output buffer before you call createWriter static method.

```
ob_end_clean();
$writer = IOFactory::createWriter($spreadsheet, 'Xlsx');
$writer->save('php://output');
```

Comment: adding ob_end_clean() fixed the problem for me

Answer (score 1):

I had the same symptom and it was because the webserver continued to output things after doing

```
$writer->save('php://output');
```

In my case it was feasible to just do a `die()` after it and the problem's gone.
Maybe it can save somebody a little time.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and `ob_end_clean();`solved my problem also. The last lines are below.

```
ob_end_clean();
$writer=new Xlsx($spreadsheet);
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.urlencode($file_name).'"');
$writer->save('php://output');
```